# Java concurrent threads Tic Tac Toe simulation

Tags: java, java-threads

Hey I tried to synchronize two threads but I can't seem to get them to work properly.

Each thread is a Player. They should wait for their turn after placing their mark. The problem is execution never stops and I'm not sure why.

If this post does not meet minimal and readible criteria, let me know I'll keep editing.

This is `TicTacToe` class.

```
public class TicTacToe {

    static char prevMark='O';
    static char[][] board;

    public TicTacToe() {
        newBoard(); // create board filled with blank spaces
    }

    public void setMark(int x, int y, char mark) {
        if(x>2||y>2||(mark!='X'&&mark!='O')) // if coordinates get outside the table or the mark is not X or O throw exception
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        if (board[x][y]==' ') { // if given place in the table is blank you can place the mark
            board[x][y] = mark;
            prevMark=mark;
        }
        else
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    public char[][] table() {
        return Arrays.stream(board).map(char[]::clone).toArray(char[][]::new);
    }

    public char lastMark() {
        return prevMark;
    }

    static private void newBoard() {
        board= new char[][]{{' ', ' ', ' '},
                {' ', ' ', ' '},
                {' ', ' ', ' '},
        };
    }

}
```

This class manages creation of the playing board, setting the marks on it and remembering the last mark placed to determine which player's turn is next.

This is `Player` interface

```
public interface Player extends Runnable{

    static boolean wonBoard(char[][] table, char mark){ //check if there is a line of 3 consecutive marks on the board
        for(int i=0; i<=2;i++){
            if(table[0][i]==mark&&table[1][i]==mark&&table[2][i]==mark)
                return true;
            if(table[i][0]==mark&&table[i][1]==mark&&table[i][2]==mark)
                return true;
        }
        if (table[0][0] == mark && table[1][1] == mark && table[2][2] == mark)
            return true;
        return table[0][2] == mark && table[1][1] == mark && table[2][0] == mark;
    }

    static Player createPlayer(final TicTacToe ticTacToe, final char mark, PlayerStrategy strategy) {

        Object foo = new Object();

        return new Player() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (foo) {
                    try {
                        do {
                            while (mark == ticTacToe.lastMark()) { // if the last placed mark is the same as this player's mark wait for the other thread
                                foo.wait();
                            }
                            ticTacToe.setMark(strategy.computeMove(mark, ticTacToe)[0], strategy.computeMove(mark, ticTacToe)[1], mark); // set the mark in place
                        } while (!wonBoard(ticTacToe.table(), mark)); //check if the board has 3 consecutive marks on any line
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This class is for determining the next move of each player and returns coordinates of the move. There shouldn't be any problems here.

```
public class PlayerStrategy {

    public int[] computeMove(final char mark, final TicTacToe ticTacToe) {
        final char[][] table = ticTacToe.table();
        int[] coordinates = new int[0];
        for (int dia = 0; dia < 5; dia++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    if (i + j == dia && table[i][j] == ' ') {
                        coordinates = new int[]{i,j};
                        return coordinates;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
}
```

Here's an example of the test.

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;

class GameTest {

    @Test
    void testPlayers() {
        testCase("" +
                        "XOO\n" +
                        "XXX\n" +
                        "O  ",
                new PlayerStrategy(), new PlayerStrategy());
    }

    private void testCase(String expected, PlayerStrategy... strategies) {
        final TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();

        final List<Thread> playerThreads = new ArrayList<>();
        final List<Character> marks = Arrays.asList('X', 'O');

        for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) {
            Player player = Player.createPlayer(ticTacToe, marks.get(i), strategies[i]);
            Thread thread = new Thread(player);
            playerThreads.add(thread);
        }

        playerThreads.forEach(Thread::start);
        playerThreads.forEach(silentConsumer(Thread::join));

        assertEquals(expected, tableString(ticTacToe.table()));
    }
}
```

Class with `tableString` method for asserting equals

```
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Utils {
    public static String tableString(char[][] table){
        return Arrays.stream(table)
                .map(String::new)
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
    }

}
```

Consumer for throws

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

@FunctionalInterface
public interface ThrowingConsumer<T, E extends Throwable> {
    void apply(T o) throws E;

    static <T, E extends Throwable> Consumer<T> silentConsumer(ThrowingConsumer<T, E> throwingConsumer) {
        return (param) -> {
            try {
                throwingConsumer.apply(param);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want help debugging your code, then I think you should post a [mcve].

Comment: Okey, I'll try. There's a lot of code required to make the wole thing work but I thougth these 2 snippets were enough to point out some obvious flaws.

Comment: @Abra hey is this too much?

Answer (score 0):

Execution never stops because both players hang onto foo.wait(); and there is no one to wake them up.

Player object should interrupt other sleeping players after making a move:

```
            do
            {
              while (mark == ticTacToe.lastMark())
              { // if the last placed mark is the same as this player's mark wait for the other thread
                try { foo.wait(); } catch (InterruptedException ex) {};
              }
              if (!wonBoard(ticTacToe.table(),'O') && !wonBoard(ticTacToe.table(),'X'))
              {
                ticTacToe.setMark(strategy.computeMove(mark, ticTacToe)[0], strategy.computeMove(mark, ticTacToe)[1], mark); // set the mark in place
              }
              for (Thread th : ticTacToe.threads) th.interrupt();
            } while (!wonBoard(ticTacToe.table(),'O') && !wonBoard(ticTacToe.table(),'X')); //check if the board has 3 consecutive marks on any line
```

Of course first you have to write down references to threads:

```
public class TicTacToe {
  
    public List<Thread> threads;
```

```
        for (int i = 0; i < marks.size(); i++) {
            Player player = Player.createPlayer(ticTacToe, marks.get(i), strategies[i]);
            Thread thread = new Thread(player);
            playerThreads.add(thread);
        }

        ticTacToe.threads=playerThreads;
        playerThreads.forEach(Thread::start);
        playerThreads.forEach(silentConsumer(Thread::join));
```